# Is the Lebesgue sigma algebra maximal w.r.t. existence of a measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $L$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}$ and $M$ a $\sigma$-algebra with $L \subseteq M$ s.t. there exists a measure $\mu:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\mu([a,b])=b-a$

Does it follow that $L=M$?

Comment: Also see : http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~piotrzak/cubo.ps. It appears that you do lose translation invariance, but you can preserve the action of a discrete group of isometries.

Comment: It is in fact consistent that there is a measure on all of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ that extends Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 2):

No. In fact, you can add any nonmeasurable set. The only necessary restriction is that the newly added set has measure between its original inner and outer measure.

Comment: But you lose translation invariance, if I recall correctly.

Comment: That may be.${}$